# Gzip used for compression returns the similar size of that of original

Tags: java, gzip

This code I have written for compressing the inputstream

```
public InputStream compress(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] inBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        gzipOutputStream.write(inBytes);
        ByteArrayInputStream retStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        gzipOutputStream.close();
        return retStream;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

It is returning the similar size's stream. Is their any bug in the code?
The input stream passed is of an image file through a test as :

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    try {
        in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testimage.jpg");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception reading file in test - ", e);
    }
    compress(in);
}
```

Comment: What sort of data are you trying to compress? Text, images, audio? Could you give some examples? Some input and outpus sizes?

Comment: There is no guarantee as to what will be the output size of a compressed archive. In some cases it can be greater than the original. Most pictures, mp3, .mpg files will not compress at all, because the data is already non-redundant.

Comment: I have tried to compress an image file

Comment: Images usually implement some sort of compression scheme already as part of the image format. Thus, trying to compress it further with gzip has little hope to make the file even smaller.

Answer (score 1):

A JPEG (.jpg) file is *already compressed*. Trying to compress it again will most likely expand it a tiny bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you compress already compressed content it wont be that much smaller (can be even bigger). Infinite compression is not possible. JPEG is already comressed (loosely). If you would GZIP bitmap or simple text file, you would notice the difference.